# take out my sql out of foreach for my code

Tags: php, sql

I have php code like that:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tabe1_data WHERE status='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
$cr_onr = array();
while($row = $db->fetchAll($q))
{
    $cr_onr[] = $row;
}


?>

<?php foreach($cr_onr as $new_cr_onr):?>

<?php $crinfo = $db->fetchOne("SELECT * FROM tabe2_data WHERE id ='".$new_cr_onr['op_id']."'");?>

<p><?=$new_cr_onr['username'];?> has been complete <?=$crinfo['op_amount'];?></p>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

I need to take `$crinfo = $db->` out of "foreach" to be before "foreach"

How i can do that please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain why you voted down.

Comment: You should use a join to get all information from the database in one query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Comment: Just an FYI and a few suggestions. You don't have to have PHP open and close tags after every statement. It is not necessary and makes your code extremely difficult to read. Suggestions: 1) try not to mix regular php tags, `<?php` with short tags `<?=`. It makes your code difficult to follow. 2) Be wary of short tags as they are not supported on all installations. In PHP 5.3 or 5.4 (don't remember which) and higher they are turned on in the php.ini file by default. However, in older versions they are not which will cause errors if you ever need to port your code to older systems.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the tables instead of having many queries:

```
$q = $db->query("

    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        tabe1_data
    INNER JOIN
        tabe2_data ON tabe1_data.op_id = tabe2_data.id
    WHERE
        tabe1_data.status='1'
    ORDER BY
        tabe1_data.id DESC
    LIMIT 10

");

$cr_onr = array();

while($row = $db->fetchAll($q))
{
    $cr_onr[] = $row;
}


?>

<?php foreach($cr_onr as $new_cr_onr):?>

<p><?=$new_cr_onr['username'];?> has been complete <?=$new_cr_onr['op_amount'];?></p>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work with me..but thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Unexpected results?

Answer (score 1):

Single joined query?

```
SELECT tabe2_data.*
FROM tabe2_data
LEFT JOIN tabe1_data ON tabe1_data.op_id = tabe2_data.id
WHERE tabe1_data.status='1'
```